# How to implement geometric div backgroud shapes in css

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to solve the following apperently simple css problem but having a little hard time with it.

My dashboard screen cotains a row of divs that currently have the default square background shape and a two letters.

I need to be able to change the backgroud shape of each square to a different geometric shape that represents the task's destination in our cms.

The shapes also needs to have a different color that represents a  status.

I need to be able to switch between the different shapes and colors (statuses).

You can see the following screenshots that illustrate what I need to achive.

Any help will be highly appriciated!

[image: uml shapes]

[image: portal preview]

Comment: Create a classname for each status and then make each background image and add it to the correct classname. Make this pure-css needs a little effort by yourself.

Comment: The new Shapes module (properties like `shape-outside` etc) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize that I couldn't get the CSS exactly like in the screenshots, but I tried my best.

It is possible to create shapes with pure CSS only. Please take a look at this snippet

```css
#shapes {
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
}

#hexagon {
  width: 25px;
  height: 13.75px;
  background: limegreen;
  position: relative;
}

#hexagon:before, #hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 12.5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 12.5px solid transparent;
  left: 0;
}

#hexagon:before {
  top: -6.25px;
  border-bottom: 6.25px solid limegreen;
}

#hexagon:after {
  bottom: -6.25px;
  border-top: 6.25px solid limegreen;
}

#hexagon:before, #hexagon:after, #diamond, #diamond:after, #star, #star-before, #star-after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#diamond {
  border: 12.5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: steelblue;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -7px;
  top: -15.5px;
}

#diamond:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -12.5px;
  top: 12.5px;
  border: 12.5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: steelblue;
}

#circle {
  padding-top: 3px;
  background: turquoise;
  border-radius: 12.5px;
}

#square {
  background: orange;
}

#trapezoid {
  border-bottom: 25px solid red;
  border-left: 6.5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6.5px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 20px;
}

#tab {
  height: 25px;
  width: 35px;
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  border-top-right-radius: 25%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25%;
}

#diamond, #circle, #square, #trapezoid, #tab, #star {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#circle, #square {
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

#square, #tab {
  text-align: center;
}

#star {
  margin: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border-right:  25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 17.5px  solid gray;
  border-left:   25px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
}

#star:before {
  border-bottom: 20px solid gray;
  border-left: 7.5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7.5px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -11.25px;
  left: -16.25px;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transform: rotate(-35deg);
}

#star:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0.75px;
  left: -26.25px;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 17.5px solid gray;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(-70deg);
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="shapes">
  <div id="hexagon">ZY</div>
  <div id="diamond">TE</div>
  <div id="circle">TE</div>
  <div id="square">TE</div>
  <div id="trapezoid">TE</div>
  <div id="tab">TE</div>
  <div id="star">TE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Richard Hamilton it's seems like the right answer. Thanks for the example appreciate it!

Comment: No problem! I wanted to learn how to do that too. It's for one of my projects as well. I found this website that helped me a bit too. https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/